# Key value pair storing and iteration in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
{
    "ordersList": [{
        "ordersDto": {
            "testMast": {
                "testId": 9,
                "testName": "HIV"
            },
            "sample": {
                "sampleId": 9050
            }
        }
    }, {

        "ordersDto": {
            "testMast": {
                "testId": 1,
                "testName": "VDRL"
            },
            "sample": null
        }
    }, {

        "ordersDto": {
            "testMast": {
                "testId": 11,
                "testName": "HIV1&2"
            },

            "sample": null
        }
    }, {
        "ordersDto": {
            "testMast": {
                "testId": 3,
                "testName": "HCB"
            },

            "sample": {
                "sampleId": 9050
            }
        }
    }, {

        "ordersDto": {
            "testMast": {
                "testId": 10,
                "testName": "HIV 1&2 Test1"
            },

            "sample": {
                "sampleId": 9051
            }
        }

    }]
}
```

Need to fetch non duplicate sample Id in an array,

```
sample Id = 9050, 9051.
```

Also I need to fetch test name for each sample Id, FOr duplicate sample Id's I need to add the testname into the same array.

```
testName = HIV, HCB // for 9050
testName = HIV 1&2 Test1" // for 9051
```

How can I populate these two arrays in one iteration.Had to fetch the testName based on sample Id value also.
Is there any key value pair storing in angular ?

Had tried with below code, which is not working as expected.

```
if (vm.ordersList== 1) { // incase of one sample Id
                res.push(vm.ordersList[0].ordersDto.testMast.testName.slice(0, 4));
                sampleId.push(angular.copy(vm.ordersList[0].ordersDto.sample.sampleId));
                sampleRcvdDate.push(angular.copy(vm.ordersList[0].ordersDto.sample.sampleRcvdOn));
              } else {
                angular.forEach(vm.ordersList, function(item) { // multiple sample id's
                  if (item.sample != null) {
                      if(item.sample.sampleId != null && sampleId.indexOf(item.sample.sampleId) == -1 ){
                        res.push(item.testMast.testName.slice(0, 4));
                        sampleId.push(angular.copy(item.sample.sampleId));
                        sampleRcvdDate.push(angular.copy(item.sample.sampleRcvdOn));
                      }
                  }
                })
              }
```

Comment: You can store the key and value pair in map

Comment: Can I update the same map value after once inserted.

Comment: Yes you can have a sampleId as key and a array of testName

Comment: can you help me in logic

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

sampleIdTestNameMap will have sampleId as key and testName list as value.

```
var sampleIdTestNameMap = {};
angular.forEach(vm.ordersList, function(item) {
    if (item.ordersDto.sample != null && item.ordersDto.sample.sampleId != null) {

        if (sampleId.indexOf(item.ordersDto.sample.sampleId) == -1) {
            sampleId.push(angular.copy(item.ordersDto.sample.sampleId));
            sampleIdTestNameMap[item.ordersDto.sample.sampleId] = [item.ordersDto.testMast.testName];
        } else {
            var tempList = [];
            tempList = sampleIdTestNameMap[item.ordersDto.sample.sampleId];
            tempList.push(item.ordersDto.testMast.testName);
            sampleIdTestNameMap[item.ordersDto.sample.sampleId] = tempList;
        }
    }
});
```